# Getting Wifi Information in a ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-wifi

The goal of what I want to achieve is to call a method that scan's using wifi for all connections and add that information to an ArrayList. I have added the code that i have tried to achieve this with before, but it doesn't get the scan results.

```
            activity.registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                    if (intent.getAction().equals(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION)) {


                        List<ScanResult> results = wifiManager.getScanResults();
                        for (int counterWifi = 0; counterWifi < results.size(); counterWifi++){
                            wifiObjects.add(new WifiObject(results.get(counterWifi).BSSID, results.get(counterWifi).SSID, results.get(counterWifi).capabilities, results.get(counterWifi).frequency, results.get(counterWifi).level));
                            Log.i("------------", "-----------------");
                        }
                    }


                }
            }, intentFilter);

            // start WiFi Scan
            wifiManager.startScan();
        }

        Log.i(TAG, wifiObjects.get(0).bBsid);
```

Update, It now gets the results but doesn't wait to add them to return. So Log.i in  the onrecieve shows the data being retrieved but it returns the arraylist with no new entry's.

Comment: Your Log.i(TAG, wifiObjects.get(0).bBsid); should be executed before the scanning is complete. Because the scanning takes a while and after the scanning is finished, an asynchronous event is fired, informing you of it's completion. Can you look at your log and post your results?

Answer (score 0):

Take care, that you have set the following permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
// perhaps this both too.
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

If this don't solve the problem, try to remove the `startScan()`

Comment: Hi, i got the information but another bug is happening. Could you see if you know how to fix this because i have no idea how to.

Answer (score 0):

Beware that you need to have access to the location informations since Android 6.0, as wifi-information can be used to track users.

With this in mind, your scan would only be successful if you have that location module in your top bar activated (as if you are using google maps for example) and have the permissions given in the post above.